# HTML form insert into MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay, this is probably super easy for all you PHP/MYSQL experts, but I'm just learning and I've hit a roadblock. I made a register form form in HTML and I want to insert the users input information in the MSQL database with PHP.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/</p>
<p>Last Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_lastname" size="25" maxlength="25" /></p>
<p>Email Address: <br><input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" size="25" maxlength="40"/><p>
<p>Create a Password: <br><input type="password" name="user_password" size="25" maxlength="40"/></p>
<p><br><input type="submit" value="register"/></p>
</form>
```

and here's my php code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "listings_db";
$tbl_name = "users"

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

if (isset($_POST['user_firstname'], 
      $_POST['user_lastname'], 
      $_POST['user_email'], 
      $_POST['user_password'], 
      $_POST['user_type'])) 
{
        $firstname = $_POST['user_firstname'];
        $lastname = $_POST['user_lastname'];
        $email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $type = $_POST['user_type'];

$errors = array();

    if(empty($firstname) 
        || empty($lastname) 
        || empty($email) 
        || empty($email) 
        || empty($password) 
        || empty($type)) 
            {$errors [] = '*All fields are required!';}     
else {
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) 
            {$errors[] = '*The email address you entered is not valid!' ;}

    if(strlen($firstname) > 25) {$errors[] = '*The email address you entered contains too many characters!';}
    if(strlen($lastname) > 25) {$errors[] = '*The first name you entered contains too many characters!';}
    if(strlen($email) > 40) {$errors[] = '*The last name you entered contains too many characters!';}   
    if(strlen($password) > 40) {$errors[] = '*The password you entered contains too many characters!';} 
    if(strlen($type) != true){$errors[] = '*Please select an account type!';}
    }

    $firstname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);
    $lastname1  = mysqli_real_escape_string($lastname);
    $email1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
    $password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);


    $query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')");
}
```

What's wrong with my code? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have `if (isset(..., $_POST['user_type']))`, but I don't see a `<input name="user_type">` in your form.

Comment: Sidenote: Missing `>` in `name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/</p>` so do `name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/></p>`

Comment: Plus, you're not passing DB connection to `$firstname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);` and others. Do `$firstname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$firstname);` etc.

Comment: Then these `('', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')` need to be `('', '$firstname1', '$lastname1', '$email1', '$password1')` --- Do go over your entire code and debug it. Whoever wants a go at putting in an answer, be my guest. I've outlined most if not all of OP's errors.

Comment: v nice Fred why dun you put an answer i want to upvote

Comment: @Fred-ii- You want me to go off and you put your answer?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was responding when the site was closed for a few minutes of air. When he sent the reply, his comments appeared.

Comment: Oh wow, I had MULTIPLE mistakes everywhere on my code. I was able to fix it with pretty much all the suggestions provided here. Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: @LucasHenrique I had to step out, didn't have time to put in an answer.

Comment: @M.chaudhry Thanks, but I didn't have time, had to leave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're new to PHP/MySQL you really shouldn't be starting out using procedural style as it's clunk and really not recommended. If you get to grips with OOP (Object Orientated Programming) now it will save you trouble in the long run!

Example:

```
mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Should become

```
 $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

and

```
    $firstname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);
```

to

```
    $firstname1 = $conn->real_escape_string($firstname);
```

When you come to writing advanced PHP (ie. classes etc.) using OOP will already be in that noodle!

Anyway, the issue you have:

**1.** You're missing the closing > from your first form element

```
<p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/></p>
```

**2.** You have also requested the post data "user_type" which you have not set as a form element

**3** you have added 1 to the variables, this isn't necessary (and also you didn't add the 1's to your query, ideally you should rename them so they are logical)

```
$firstname1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);
$lastname1  = mysqli_real_escape_string($lastname);
$email1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
$password1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
```

Should changed to

```
$firstname_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($firstname);
$lastname_escaped  = mysqli_real_escape_string($lastname);
$email_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($email);
$password_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string($password);
```

**4** You don't need to INSERT columns that (should be set up as auto increment) as it will do it automatically

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')");
```

Should be

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO users (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')");
```

**5**
**!!!!You are not encrypting the password being inputted into the database!!!!!**
At the very LEAST you should slap that sucker with

```
 $password = md5($_POST['user_password']); //added md5 encryption
```

Although it is highly recommended to use the [PHPass library](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) as it uses PHP's crypt() functionality without having to work out all the headaches!

Comment: Thank you!! As far as encrypting the passwords, yes, I totally agree, however I'm just trying to work on an amateur project to improve my knowledge, but I'll definitely take encrypting into consideration when working with professional projects. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, although you should ALWAYS do it, even with your own testing stuff. It solidifies it in your mind so that it is second nature :)

Comment: Just to add that szpal suggests using pattern and required for the forms. It is only supported by Firefox 4+ & Chrome 5+ & Opera 9.6+ & MSIE 10+ (I can't comment on his answer >.<)

Comment: MD5 shouldn't be used for password storage. It's old and considered too "fast". Do change this to reflect a better password storage method such as `bcrypt` or PHP 5.5 `password_hash()` function.

Comment: Answer updated , "I did say at the very least" :P but you're right. Added link to PHPass

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/</p>
```

Change to, because lacked `>`

```
<p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_firstname" size="25 maxlength="25"/></p>
```

**AND**

`$_POST['user_type']` not exist in HTML or declared in PHP.

**AND**

Your variables are

`('', '$firstname1', '$lastname1', '$email1', '$password1')`

Comment: Oh wow, I had MULTIPLE mistakes everywhere on my code. I was able to fix it with pretty much all the suggestions provided here. Thank you so much for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the HTML5 'required' and 'pattern' attributes, and your PHP code will be much shorter.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <p>First Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_firstname" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}" required /></p>
  <p>Last Name: <br><input type="text" name="user_lastname" size="25" maxlength="25" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1,25}" required /></p>
  <p>Email Address: <br><input type="email" id="email" name="user_email" size="25" maxlength="40" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" required /><p>
  <p>Create a Password: <br><input type="password" name="user_password" size="25" maxlength="40" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,40}" required /></p>
  <p><br><input type="submit" value="register"/></p>
</form>
```

And the PHP script:

```
$host     = "localhost";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "listings_db";
$tbl_name = "users";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_firstname']);
$lastname  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_lastname']);
$email     = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
$password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['user_password']);

$query = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (user_firstname, user_lastname, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$password')");
```

Comment: When the new form fields and attributes have wider browser support then yes, but to use this now, you'd also need to add a javascript fallback, which defeats the purpose of making it simpler

Comment: The required and pattern attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, no need javascript.